# Code structure in Multisites Scenario

Tags: jss

We want to use `Sitecore JSS (ReactBased) Framework with Sitecore 9.2` (Integrated mode.

We have multisite environment where each site is subset of Global Site.
It means templates/rendering created in Global Sites will be reused in brand sites.

Form Sitecore tree we can able to use Templates and rendering from Global Sites,
But when we run a brand site with global rendering on it, It is not working because the related JSS code is not present in brand JSS App codebase.

Can you suggest how we can deal with this Scenario and how to inherit global sites templates/rendering to brand sites in JSS Code Base.

We have 2 JSS APP running on different domain (Integrated mode) as below:

1. Global APP---/Dist/global-app ---www.XXX-Global.Com
2. Brand App---/Dist/brand-app   ---www.XXX.brand.com

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you install the latest SXA 1.9 and use the integration with JSS which is present there. This will allow you to use:

- SXA site management for JSS apps
- Cross-site presentation sharing using page designs and partial designs
- Cross-site content sharing
- Cross-site reusability of renderings
- Cross-site linking

In this case, templates (the same as in SXA) are shared across a Tenant. So whole JSS sites which you will have under JSS tenant will use the same templates (which is your case).

For more details take a look here: [Managing JSS apps with SXA](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/managing-jss-apps-with-sxa.html)

Comment: Here we are looking from JSS Code perspective , not from Sitecore perspective.